# How to send data from server to client in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I'm running a server in nodejs with express to serve an html form within the file index.html to a client like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser());
app.get('/', function(req, res){res.sendfile('index.html');});
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  res.json(req.body);
});

app.listen(8080);
```

`req.body` gives me the form input. Now I need to send back req.body to the client, and to do this I'm using ajax on the client side (inside index.html) like this:

```
var data;
$('#submit').click(function()
{
    console.log('Button Clicked');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        type:'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function(data) {

            console.log(data);
        });      
})
```

However when I click the button `submit` I get `Object {}` in the browser console and not the form input.
What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't think you're using the body parser correctly. https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: You are sending a JSON string and your server is converting to a JSON Object, which you are then returning - but not as a string.  Try `res.json(JSON.stringify(req.body));`

Comment: the result of that was {}

Comment: @Vic res.json expects an object, not json. :)

Comment: I think you should use bodyparser something like `app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/json'}));`

Comment: `var data;`. is this variable properly intiialised?

Comment: @KevinB - my fault that is correct. So 1) set data to something and 2) change to `res.json(req.body.data);`

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code:

First, as the comments mention, `bodyParser()` is deprecated, you should be using the specific bodyParser middlewares (json, text, urlencoded, raw). So in your case:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Second, your client side call to jQuery.ajax should stringify your data. Like this:

```
$('#submit').click(function()
{
    console.log('Button Clicked');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        type:'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });      
})
```

Comment: also didn't work. Do you know where can I find any clear examples of this?

Comment: It works for me... Are you assigning var data a value or is it undefined like in your code sample? What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'?